# Remove field from redux store

Tags: redux-form

Is there a way to unset/remove a variable set with `change` method?
In my code I programmatically set a field this way

```
this.props.change('extraBedChildrenNum', 1);
```

but I would like to unset this field so it is removed from the store. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is not action creator to remove a field from a form provided to the decorated for component as a prop, but [there is one exported by redux-form](http://redux-form.com/6.8.0/docs/api/ActionCreators.md/) called `unregisterField`.

So you should be able to do something like this:

```
store.dispatch(unregisterField('MyFormName', 'extraBedChildrenNum'))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From [github issue](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/709)

```
import {change} from 'redux-form';

dispatch(change('myForm', 'myField', 'newValue'))
```

this should help

Comment: This will set the `myField` to `newValue`; what I need is to remove `myField`  from `myForm`.